# Is there a problem with yt-dlp when it is used with Linux Mint 20.3 Una?

Tags: linux, yt-dlp

I have found problems when downloading extracts from youtube videos using yt-dlp

My operating system is Linux Mint 20.3 Una

I would be grateful if the problem could be identified.

This is what I am using to do the download from the Terminal:

yt-dlp --postprocessor-args "-ss start time -t end time" -o Ravel_Bolero -f bv*+ba [https://youtu.be/E9PiL5icwic>](https://youtu.be/E9PiL5icwic%3E) yt-dl-progress.txt

and only certain start and end time combinations seem to be problematic.
For example:
with a start time of 00:10:00 and end time 00:19:00 actual length recorded is 7:22 instead of 9mins
with a start time of 00:10:00 and end time 00:20:00 actual length recorded is 7:22 instead of 10mins
with a start time of 00:10:00 and end time 00:21:00 actual length recorded is 7:22 instead of 11mins
with a start time of 00:10:00 and end time 00:22:00 actual length recorded is 7:22 instead of 12mins
with a start time of 00:10:00 and end time 00:23:00 actual length recorded is 7:22 instead of 13mins
with a start time of 00:09:00 and end time 00:19:00 actual length recorded is 8:22 instead of 10mins
with a start time of 00:09:00 and end time 00:20:00 actual length recorded is 8:22 instead of 11mins
with a start time of 00:09:00 and end time 00:21:00 actual length recorded is 8:22 instead of 12mins
with a start time of 00:09:00 and end time 00:22:00 actual length recorded is 8:22 instead of 13mins
with a start time of 00:09:00 and end time 00:30:00 actual length recorded is 8:22 instead of 21mins

Similarly with start time of 00:08:00 and other diferent end times the actual recorded length is always 9:22

With start and end times of other values tested, the actual recorded length is as it should be
eg with a start time of 00:06:00 and end time 00:16:00 actual length recorded is 10:00
and with a start time of 00:05:00 and end time 00:15:00 actual length recorded is 10:00
with a start time of  00:04:00 and end time  00:34:00 actual length recorded is 30:00
and with a start time of 00:06:00 and an end time of 00:31:00 the actual recorded length was 25:00

Comment: I don't know how you could have missed this.  Your first video is exactly 17:22 in length.  If you start at 10:00, then OF COURSE you can't get more than 7:22, because that's all there is.

Comment: You are completely right, I appologise for wasting the time of the experts.  What Tim Roberts was too kind to say is that the total length of the video clip was 17:22mins and I should have checked the finishing time..